# Shiny R: Subset rows in data frame

Tags: r, shiny, subset

I am trying to run models by certain factor levels or groups of these levels by using a select input widget in Shiny.

When I subset by one factor level, I get the correct model results. But when I try to run a model that includes all factor levels or groups of the levels, I do not get the correct model estimates.

For example, the correct model estimates when all factor levels are included (i.e. the model is run over the entire data frame) are:
[image]

But when I run my app and select all the levels of my factor variable, which represents different geographical regions, I obtain different results:
[image]

My question is how can I specify my reactive sub-setting function to accommodate all factor levels or groups of the levels?

**Code for individual models that includes all levels and models by factor level for reference:**

```
library(mlogit)
data("Heating", package = "mlogit")
mlogit(depvar ~ ic + oc | 0, data= Heating, shape = "wide", choice = "depvar", varying = c(3:12))
mlogit(depvar ~ ic + oc | 0, data= Heating[Heating$region=="ncostl" , ], shape = "wide", choice = "depvar", varying = c(3:12))
mlogit(depvar ~ ic + oc | 0, data= Heating[Heating$region=="scostl" , ], shape = "wide", choice = "depvar", varying = c(3:12))
mlogit(depvar ~ ic + oc | 0, data= Heating[Heating$region=="mountn" , ], shape = "wide", choice = "depvar", varying = c(3:12))
mlogit(depvar ~ ic + oc | 0, data= Heating[Heating$region=="valley" , ], shape = "wide", choice = "depvar", varying = c(3:12))
```

**Shiny code:**

```
### PART 1 - Load Libraries and Data
library(shiny)           # For running the app
library(mlogit)

#### data
data("Heating", package = "mlogit")

#### PART 2 - Define User Interface for application
ui <- fluidPage(

  ## Application title
  titlePanel("Housing Preference"),

  ## Sidebar with user input elements
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      p("Select the inputs"), # Header
      # Speciality
      selectInput('regiontype', 'Region', choices = c("northern coastal region"= "ncostl", 
                                               "southern coastal region" = "scostl", 
                                               "mountain region"  = "mountn",
                                               "central valley region"= "valley"), multiple=TRUE, selectize=TRUE)

    ),

    ## Show a plot
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("summary")
    )
  )
)

#### PART 3 - Define server logic required to run calculations and draw plots
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$summary <- renderPrint({

    df <- Heating

    ### Subset data
    df.subset <- reactive({ a <- subset(df, region == input$regiontype)
    return(a)})

    ### Model 
    estimates <- mlogit(depvar ~ ic + oc | 0, data= df.subset(), shape = "wide", choice = "depvar", varying = c(3:12))
    summary(estimates)


  })
}

### PART 4 - Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your use of `==` in subset.

Let's take a look at your data:

```
table(Heating$region)

#> valley scostl mountn ncostl 
#>    177    361    102    260
```

900 rows, `scostl` and `ncostl` account for 621 of your rows. However, when I subset passing in a vector of matches only 305 are returned.

```
nrow(subset(Heating, region == c("ncostl","scostl")))
#> [1] 305
```

What happened? Why isn't it 621? **Vector recycling** is biting you here.  Because `Heating$region` and `c("ncostly","scostl")` aren't the same length, the shorter one is repeated until they are the same length. So you're actually filtering on the pattern of `ncostl`, `scostl` and returning those matches.

Instead, you want to use the `%in%` operator.

```
nrow(subset(Heating, region %in% c("ncostl","scostl")))
#> [1] 621
```

Now, there's no vector recycling because each element of `Heating$region` is checked for membership in the list you provide.

The reason you're getting a vector is that's the output from a multiple `selectInput` in shiny.

Comment: thank you very much. `%in` worked. After reading your answer, it still is a bit of a mystery to me though as why I am getting the same model results when I select all the regions in the app or run the model over the entire data frame outside the app. Simply by using the `%in%` operator, I do not have to explicitly create the level grouping, e.g. c("ncostl","scostl"), in the select input?

Comment: When you're filtering the data, the `%in%` operator avoids the vector recycling issue that gets the wrong subset of data. That one change for me produced the correct results.